# The meaning of preposition 'by'

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I get a bit confused about the meaning of the preposition *by* in 'by the other side' in the context below. Could you help to explain it for me in detail?

> The Rat got hold of an oar and shoved it under the Mole's arm;then he did the same by the other side of him and, hauled him out...
>
> — *The Wind in the Willows,* Kenneth Grahame (1859–1932), pub 1908

In addition, I have searched the meaning of [*by* in Longman's dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/by) and it comes out with many different meaning. My problem is I am not sure which meaning it should be in the situation of my case.

Comment: It's a rather old-fashioned equivalent of 'did the same _to_ the other side'. I can't find the usage in your Longmans link, probably because it's so old. Incidentally, the book is '_The_ Wind in the _Willows_'.

Comment: I've added dates into the question when tidying it a little, because usage of English can change rapidly in a short time, and — particularly in novels, perhaps — it is very much a product of its time.

Comment: @KateBunting I basically agree but don't you think that it often carries the implication of _for_ or _on behalf of_? As a made up example "Mr Fortescue did well by his niece, his provision of a dowry enabled her to marry Sir Jasper". I have deliberately tried to invoke period writing, of course.

Comment: 'By the other side of him' is quite clever, I think. It seems to me to mean 'beside, but on the other side'.

Comment: @BoldBen A 1930s Concise Oxford Dictionary (which I keep for its definitions of older words) defines this sense of 'by' as 'concerning, in respect of'.

Comment: @KateBunting I don't disagree, I just just wanted to emphasise what I consider to be the, usually supportive and almost always personal, implications of using 'by'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have searched the meaning of *by*

You should have searched for the meaning of ***do***, where ***[do by](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/do+by)*** is listed as a phrasal verb:

> to treat in the manner specified: *employers do well by hard working
>   employees*.

Answer (score 1):

... then he did the same [by](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/by) the other side of him and, hauled him out.

> 5. beside; next to;

My sense is meaning he used the 2nd oar on the 'the other side' for a 2 oar carry, litter or sked.

Comment: Undoubtedly that's what it means.

Comment: @KateBunting  the OP asked ... the OP got!